Vertical lines on laptop screen caused by the FFC cable
TL; DR: Vertical lines appeared on my laptop screen, it's most likely the FFC cable on the panel and I'm looking for a way to fix the issue without replacing the screen
Recently I've been working on a small personal project, restoring an old beaten up G751JY that I got from a thrift market. Got a new motherboard from aliexpress, glued all the broken parts, full cleanup, etc. Finally, after weeks of waiting and work, getting some spare parts and fixing CPU heat issues (incomplete heatsink contact), I was finally done - custom vBIOS, CPU and GPU undervolted and overclocked, extra RAM. Runs beautifully and can be used for any game that was not released in the past year or two.
But not even 3 days after I was done a black line appears on screen, soon joined by another one next to it. A really demoralizing feeling after spending all this time and effort to restore this ancient beast. The issue is definitely hardware related and from what I gather it's a problem with the FFC cable on the LCD panel.
https://imgur.com/a/uM3H62q
You can see in the video that applying pressure to the area where the ribbon cable is housed has an effect on the lines. Btw the display has already been replaced in the past - I know this because there is a cut along the metal on the lid to house the panel! The panel in question is the LG LP173WF4-SPF1 LGD0469, while this model of Asus usually comes with the LG LP173WF4-SPD1.
I really don't feel like drop another 100+ euro on this machine since I was restoring it because I enjoyed the process and to have an extra PC for improvised LAN parties or server stuff. I've already spent enough time and money.
I've read that it can be a connection issue and can potentially be fixed with a solder wrapped in aluminum foil or a heatgun. I'm pretty alright with the solder. My plan for now is to carefully peel off/cut open the bottom side of the panel (the one that says “Don’t Touch”, check with a microscope for any obvious signs of the issue and carefully treat the area with the solder iron at low heat and wrapped in foil. Obviously with all the precautions - panel and battery are disconnected at all times, anti-static wrist wrap and gloves to avoid leaving any acidic oils.
So I want to know if anyone has done this before and if it is possible to fix the FFC cable.

Solid vertical lines is more likely a fault in the panel itself, or in the address decoder connected directly to the panel. The FFC cable will be transferring bulk data describing the entire screen rather than particular columns or rows. I would expect an FFC fault to end up having some kind of random looking visual noise or to not work at all.

What makes you believe the cable has wires mapped to a specific column of pixels?? If that line does not move, it's nothing to do with the cable. Try an external monitor, and if it works, just use that.

@Mokubai in hindsight it was a pretty naive idea to think that the ribbon cable has individual connections for that can affect the screen in such a manner. I've never dealt with screen panels in depth so thanks for this clarification.

With that said, do you think this can be fixed or should I look for a replacement panel?
@DrMoishePippik, using it with an external monitor defats its purpose for me and makes it much more cumbersome to use.
